# Convergence of means and convergence in mean

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Assume $(X_n)$ for $n \geq 0$ uniformly integrable and  $X_n \to X$ in probability. I want to show that $X_n \to X$ in $L^1$. I will probably have to achieve this with some bounding of $E[|X-X_n|]$. Convergence in probability implies convergence in distribution, and together with Skorokhod's theorem, this implies $E[X_n]\to E[X]$, but I don't think this can be used to bound $E[|X-X_n|]$. Any idea how to proceed?

Comment: Hint: Use indicator functions to split the expectation into where $|X-X_n| > \varepsilon$ and where $|X - X_n| \le \varepsilon$

Comment: It is the intuitive move in this situation, but one of the two estimates I obtain seems possibly even harder than the first, namely $E[|X_n-X|\mathbb{1}_{|X_n-X| \geq \epsilon}]$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, observe that $X$ is integrable, by applying Fatou's lemma to $\lvert X_{n_k}\rvert$, where $(X_{n_k})$ is such that $X_{n_k}\to X$ almost surely. Hence the sequence $(Y_n)_{n\geqslant 1}$ defined by $Y_n=\lvert X_n-X\rvert$ is uniformly integrable and converges in probability to $0$. In order to show the convergence in $\mathbb L^1$, recall that $\mathbb EY_n=\int_0^\infty\mathbb P(Y_n>t)dt$. Let $f_n(t):= \mathbb P(Y_n>t)$. Since $Y_n\to 0$ in probability, $f_n(t)\to 0$ for each positive $t$ which is a good start, but we cannot conclude yet (which is normal, as we did not use uniform integrability yet). Write for a fixed $R$
$$
\mathbb EY_n=\int_0^R\mathbb P(Y_n>t)dt+ \int_R^\infty\mathbb P(Y_n\mathbf{1}_{\{Y_n>R\}}>t)dt.
$$
The second term of the right hand side is smaller than $\mathbb E\left[Y_n\mathbf{1}_{\{Y_n>R\}}\right]$ hence
$$\tag{*}
\mathbb EY_n\leqslant \int_0^R\mathbb P(Y_n>t)dt+\sup_{k\geqslant 1}\mathbb E\left[Y_k\mathbf{1}_{\{Y_k>R\}}\right].
$$
As $n$ goes to infinity (for fixed $R$), $\int_0^R\mathbb P(Y_n>t)dt\to 0$ because $\int_0^R\mathbb P(Y_n>t)dt\leqslant R\mathbb P(Y_n>\varepsilon)+\varepsilon$
hence taking the $\limsup_{n\to\infty}$ in (*) and using uniform integrability finishes the proof.

Comment: Thanks. Just one question, $X$ is UI because any single r.v. in $L^1$ us UI?

Comment: Also, you use Fatou in $E[|\liminf X_{n_k}|] \leq \liminf E[|X_{n_k}|] \to E[|X|]$, but I only know $\liminf E|X_{n_k}] \to  E[X]$. What am I missing?

Comment: I only said that $X$ is integrable, not uniformly integrable (although it is true that the sequence consisting only of $X$ is uniformly integrable). $\liminf E[\lvert X_{n_k}\rvert]$ does not exceed $\sup_j E[\lvert X_j\rvert]$.

Comment: Ok, so basically you don't need the convergence bit, you are only bounding, ofc. Thanks.

Comment: One more thing, if you feel like answering. With the exact same assumptions on $X$, $X_n$, how would you bound $E[|X_n-X|\mathbb{1}_{|X_n|\leq M, |X| \leq M}]$?

Comment: You can use the dominated convergence theorem (after having passed to an almost convergent subsequence).

Comment: How would that control what happens for the $X_n$ that don't belong to the  convergent subsequence?

Comment: We can show that for each subsequence, you can extract a further subsequence which converges in $L^1$.